# How to make X axis time series label displays only every 6 hour C3?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I used C3 JS for my graph but my X axis isn't nice. How should I do to make the X axis looks like this (display time label at every 6 hour and start at 00:00)? 
[image]

Edit: This is my sample code!

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        size: {
            height: 320,
            width: 1100
        },
        data: {
            x: 'date',
            x_format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            json: result,
            keys: {
                x: 'created_at',
                value: ['AQI']
            },
            type: 'bar'
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 1
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: "%I:00\n%a"
                },
                label: 'Time',
                extent: [1, 10],
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: my current chart]

Comment: Please add a sample code. Add what you have already got so we can try to help you by looking at that. Without knowing the structure of your data, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal Would you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, what do you want to know @tuanctob48 ?

Comment: How should i change the time format in my code to get the x axis like the picture on top? Thank you.

Comment: Hey, yeah, can you create a fiddle and send the link? I'll have a look and tell you!